« En Paris », « en d'autres nuits » ?
Dans La Volonté du Roi Krogold (1939/40), légende médiévale écrite par Céline, j'ai trouvé ce passage :

Tébaut tout accablé du meurtre… d’avoir occis le capitaine… là-bas
en Paris… puis le pauvre galant badin… encore deux ou trois hommes d’armes… par-ci par-là… en d’autres nuits… à la débauche…

Est-ce que cet usage de en a des racines dans l'ancien français, ou s'agit-il d'une licence poétique de Céline ?

Que ce soit l'un ou l'autre, ça sonne définitivement viellot :-)

Le passage cité utilise un français qui reprend du vocabulaire et des tournures surannées (occire, galant badin, hommes d'armes).
En Paris, qui ne se dit plus, était parfois utilisé, plutôt jusqu'au milieu du XVIIe siècle :

Lors il fut ordonné que le Roy, ses oncles, & les Seigneurs principalement , entreroyent en Paris, & aucuns Gens-d'armes : mais les plus grosses routes se tiendroyent au dehors de Paris, tout à l'environ , pour donner cremeur aux Parisiens. Jean Froissart, Chroniques

À Paris a toujours été beaucoup plus courant, en revanche en d’autres nuits bien que rare peut encore se rencontrer en français contemporain.

de suranné? Je croyais que suranné ne pouvait être qu'un adjectif?

Bien sûr, je ne sais pas pourquoi j'ai mis ce de.

En Avignon, en Arles se disent couramment et il est presque aussi courant de considérer à Avignon, à Arles incorrects. La liaison est bien sûr obligatoire: c'est l'hiatus qui fait froncer les sourcils.

@FrançoisJurain C'est une méprise. Quand il s'agit des villes et pas du pays, en Avignon et en Arles est principalement dit par les journalistes parisiens. Je n'ai jamais entendu d'Arlésien ou d'Avignonnais dire en A... sauf les rares qui le disent en provençal ("Je vais à Avignon" : vau en Avignoun ou vau a n'Avignoun). D'autre part, à la différence de l'anglais, l'aversion du français pour l'hiatus est souvent un mythe. Enchaîner des voyelles ne nous pose généralement aucun problème de prononciation.
